# calling a function of a class created in class in php

Tags: php, oop

Here is the code layout outline all nicely laid out in 3 file and class's

```
$aa = new className();
class className {
    /**
    * Constructor
    */
    function className() {
        $this->init_SubClass();
    }

    function init_SubClass() {
        require_once('sub_class.class.php');
        $sub_class = new sub_class();
    }
}
```

sub_class.class.php

```
   class sub_class {
    /**
    * Constructor
    */
    function sub_class() {
        $this->init_Sub_Sub_Class();
    }

    function init_Sub_Sub_Class() {
        require_once('Sub_Sub_Class.class.php');
        $Sub_Sub_Class = new Sub_Sub_Class();
    }
}
```

sub_sub_class.class.php

```
class Sub_Sub_Class {
    public function function_I_to_call() {
        echo ' show this text'
    }
}
```

How to a call function_I_to_call()

This was mybest guess so far

```
$aa->className->sub_class->function_I_to_call()
```

Not sure how to do this or if it can be done.

Many Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? It sort of looks like you are trying to get toward some sort of Polymorphism, but I cannot tell - how are you intending this code to execute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not assigning the newly created object to the instance. You need to use

```
$this->sub_class = new Subclass;
```

That will make them [public](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) properties and then you can use your

```
$aa = new className;
$aa->sub_class->function_I_to_call();
```

However, the entire approach is completely flawed:

- The constructor should be `__construct`. The old style constructor is a relic from PHP4 times and [wont work with namespaced classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).
- Assigning properties on the fly is considered bad practice, because it's unobvious they exist when looking at the API. [Declare them as members in the class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).
- Calls to `require` are unneeded when you use an [Autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).
- Use [Dependency Injection](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection) to [decouple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) your components. Makes them easier to [unit-test](http://www.phpunit.de/) as well.
- If you need to assemble complex [collaborator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborator_%28programming%29) graphs, use a [Factory](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) or a [Builder](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder) [pattern](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Design_Patterns) instead.

Alternate approach

```
class Foo
{
    protected $bar;
    public function __construct(Bar $bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
```

And then `Bar`

```
class Bar
{
    protected $baz;
    public function __construct(Baz $baz)
    {
        $this->baz = $baz;
    }
    public function getBaz()
    {
        return $this->baz;
    }
}
```

And `Baz`:

```
class Baz
{
    public function fn()
    {
        return 'called';
    }
}
```

And then assemble it via:

```
$foo = new Foo(new Bar(new Baz));
```

Or move that code to a Factory:

```
class FooFactory
{
    public function create()
    {
        return new Foo(new Bar(new Baz));
    }
}
```

Finally, the Autoloader (simplified):

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    $classMap = array(
        'Foo' => '/path/to/Foo.php',
        'Bar' => '/path/to/Bar.php',
        'Baz' => '/path/to/Baz.php',
    );
    require $classMap[$className];
});
```

And then you *could* call ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WJv7sC))

```
$fooFactory = new FooFactory;
$foo = $fooFactory->create();
echo $foo->getBar()->getBaz()->fn();
```

But you shouldnt (unless it's some sort of DSL), because that is violating [Law of Demeter](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) because you are digging too deep into the collaborators.

Comment: the advice seems to rewrite it
Let me think about that and I will ready the links
Many Thanks for the detail reply

Comment: @Pbearne you are welcome. Also have a look at https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29 and https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29 and http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=The+Clean+Code+Talks&aq=f